# How to share plain text to facebook messenger from an android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-messenger

I am trying to share a plain text to messenger app from my application using facebook sdk 4.x but I am not able to configure the contentUri for that, However when I send image it works.

How to do this for plain text?

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://in.darpankulkarni.l33ttxtformessenger/mipmap/ic_launcher");
// contentUri points to the content being shared to Messenger
   ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
        ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(contentUri, "image/png").setExternalUri(Uri.parse("https://montanaflynn-l33t-sp34k.p.mashape.com/encode?text=Hello+How+the+hell+are+you!&mashape-key=AD8dVisiLdmshFoLegK2hzNoDQI4p1BDlshjsn50fOqenOnPY7"))
                        .build();

// Sharing from an Activity
   MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
                this,
                REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
                shareToMessengerParams);
```

How to send plain text using above code?

Comment: This is by design. We only allow images and video mime types right now.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/1cb3863835ccf10d4ee6e1919a02f7d4e76748b9/facebook/src/com/facebook/messenger/ShareToMessengerParams.java#L41

Comment: Whats the sense of only sharing images and videos?... There is nothing simpler than sharing text...

Answer (score 2):

The supported MessengerUtils methods don't allow for sharing text. The following worked for me:

```
ShareLinkContent.Builder shareLinkContentBuilder = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentDescription(contentDescription)
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url));
shareLinkContentBuilder.setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(activity);
messageDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
messageDialog.show(shareLinkContentBuilder.build());
```

The share link content was obtained from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: This works well. It's too bad Facebook decided to deprecate the `setImageUrl()`